# Do I need to save the value of a get function to make my code more performant over memory-consumption?

Tags: javascript, performance, class

The title may be confusing so here's what I mean, let say I have this simple class

```js
import { mixer } from './kitchen';

type Food = { type: 'fruit'|'vegetable', name: string }

class Fridge {
  food: Food[] = []

  get fruits () { return food.filter(f => f.type == 'fruit') }

  mixFruits1 () {
    console.log(`Mixing ${this.fruits.length} together`)
    mixer(this.fruits)
    console.log(`You have mixed ${this.fruits.map(f => f.name).join(', ')} together`)

    // notice in this function I have called `this.fruits` 3 times
    // which is a get "function"
  }

  mixFruits2 () {
    const fruits = this.fruits
    console.log(`Mixing ${fruits.length} together`)
    mixer(fruits)
    console.log(`You have mixed ${fruits.map(f => f.name).join(', ')} together`)

    // notice in this function I am storing `this.fruits` (one call) into a local variable
  }
}
```

My question is this one : is `mixFruits2` technically better than `mixFruits1` performance-wise?
Because in `mixFruits1` I am calling `this.fruits` 3 times (technically 3 function calls), or is JavaScript internally doing this pre-processing routine so we don't have to do it ourselves?

Comment: <Subjective>I'd argue that `fruits` shouldn't be a getter *at all*. It does too much work. It should be a `getFruits` function so it's clear at point of use that it's a call. Getters should do **very, very** little work (like, accessing a private field), and should mostly be used for access control, not data manipulation. **If** it's going to be a getter, it should memoize its return value so it only has to recalculate it if `food` changes.</Subjective>

Comment: Removing the `console.log` will help more than that the other change - but those should never go in deployed code anyway.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss you realize the `console.log` here are only to provide an example to the problem? This is not my code of course.

Comment: I make no assumptions on code present unless specifically stated.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss but the question is not about whether it is a good thing to use `console.log` here or not anyway... The question is both specifically stated in the title and in the body. I don't know what you assume.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into "better" or "worse" (opinion-based, off-topic for Stack Overflow), there's really no argument for repeating the `filter` three times when you could do it once as you have in `mixFruits2`.

That said, it's doing presentation, and unless you have *millions* of elements in `food`, the difference is unlikely to be apparent to the user.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but to be totally honest with you that doesn't shed any light on what I am asking here. How could you be so sure JavaScript devs didn't take an extra hour to think the problem and make the "get function" more wise than just a regular function? sure it acts as a function but you can't be sure what a common interpreter is doing with that command.

Comment: @vdegenne - Because A) [nothing in the specification says so](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-validateandapplypropertydescriptor) -- the function you supply is associated with the property and is called when the property is accessed, every time; and B) That would be way, way beyond appropriate optimization. Suppose something else changes `food` in the meantime? Sure, the engine could record what properties were accessed during the getter and monitor changes to them, but that would be overhead it has no place adding. It definitely does not.

Comment: C) It would be *observable*. If the engine magically optimized `fruits` to avoid repeating the `filter`, it would have to return the same array when used twice, and if the first caller changed the array, that would be observable to the second caller (and vice-versa). (To avoid *that*, the engine would have to add overhead to make arrays share backing storage, and copy-on-write, which again is just well beyond what JavaScript engines do -- or should do. That's left to the program author, who has a better understanding of the problem being solved.)